# No data-transition animation when redirect to a div with parameter in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have this line of code

```
$('#allList').append('<li><a href="?id='#DeadlineDetail" data-transition = "flow" >'+ allDeadline.class +'<br>'+ allDeadline.duedate+'  '+ allDeadline.duetime+'<br>'+ allDeadline.description +'</a></li>');
```

that can redirect to the div "DeadlineDetail" with data-transition animation . However, if I add the  parameter into the href like this

```
$('#allList').append('<li><a href="?id='+allDeadline.id+'#DeadlineDetail" data-transition = "flow" >'+ allDeadline.class +'<br>'+ allDeadline.duedate+'  '+ allDeadline.duetime+'<br>'+ allDeadline.description +'</a></li>');
```

There will be no data-transition animation

Any solution for this ?

Full HTML and JS in JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XqE5P/

Comment: Welcome to SO... How do i trigger the above code in the fiddle..? it looks like you've dumped all the code including sql queries in the fiddle... please include only the relevant code so that it's easy to debug and get to the problem...

Comment: I updated my code. If you can, please help me